# Why can't I generate a signed APK?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, gradle

I have an app, that works just the way I want it to and in the past I was able to generate signed APKs.
However now in my newest version (1.11) I can't build a signed akp anymore. This thing gets shown to me:

```
Executing tasks: [:app:assembleRelease] in project C:\Users\Gereon\AndroidStudioProjects\Akkubuch

> Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:javaPreCompileRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mainApkListPersistenceRelease
> Task :app:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:createReleaseCompatibleScreenManifests
> Task :app:extractDeepLinksRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processReleaseManifest
> Task :app:processReleaseResources
> Task :app:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:lintVitalRelease FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:lintVitalRelease'.
> Lint infrastructure error
  Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.android.tools.lint.gradle.api.ReflectiveLintRunner.runLint(ReflectiveLintRunner.kt:38)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.LintBaseTask.runLint(LintBaseTask.java:114)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.LintPerVariantTask.lint(LintPerVariantTask.java:63)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:103)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.doExecute(StandardTaskAction.java:49)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:42)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:28)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:717)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:684)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$5.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:476)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:402)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:394)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:92)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:461)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:444)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.access$200(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:93)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$TaskExecution.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:237)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.lambda$execute$1(ExecuteStep.java:33)
    at java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:267)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupOutputsStep.execute(CleanupOutputsStep.java:58)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupOutputsStep.execute(CleanupOutputsStep.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:48)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CancelExecutionStep.execute(CancelExecutionStep.java:39)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.executeWithoutTimeout(TimeoutStep.java:73)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.execute(TimeoutStep.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CatchExceptionStep.execute(CatchExceptionStep.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:51)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SnapshotOutputsStep.execute(SnapshotOutputsStep.java:45)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SnapshotOutputsStep.execute(SnapshotOutputsStep.java:31)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.executeWithoutCache(CacheStep.java:208)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:70)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:45)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.execute(BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.java:49)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreSnapshotsStep.execute(StoreSnapshotsStep.java:43)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreSnapshotsStep.execute(StoreSnapshotsStep.java:32)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:38)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.executeBecause(SkipUpToDateStep.java:96)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.lambda$execute$0(SkipUpToDateStep.java:89)
    at java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:215)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:38)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:76)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:37)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:48)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:69)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:47)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultWorkExecutor.execute(DefaultWorkExecutor.java:33)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:140)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:108)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveBeforeExecutionOutputsTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveBeforeExecutionOutputsTaskExecuter.java:67)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveAfterPreviousExecutionStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveAfterPreviousExecutionStateTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:94)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:95)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:43)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:355)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:343)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:336)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:322)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:134)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:202)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:193)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
  Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid main APK outputs : EarlySyncBuildOutput(type=com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.InternalArtifactType$APK@78c5bc70, apkType=MAIN, filtersData=[], version=0, output=C:\Users\Gereon\AndroidStudioProjects\Akkubuch\app\release\Akkubuch - V.1.1.apk),EarlySyncBuildOutput(type=com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.InternalArtifactType$APK@78c5bc70, apkType=MAIN, filtersData=[], version=0, output=C:\Users\Gereon\AndroidStudioProjects\Akkubuch\app\release\Akkubuch - V.1.10.apk),EarlySyncBuildOutput(type=com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.InternalArtifactType$APK@78c5bc70, apkType=MAIN, filtersData=[], version=0, output=C:\Users\Gereon\AndroidStudioProjects\Akkubuch\app\release\Akkubuch - V.1.2.apk),EarlySyncBuildOutput(type=com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.InternalArtifactType$APK@78c5bc70, apkType=MAIN, filtersData=[], version=0, output=C:\Users\Gereon\AndroidStudioProjects\Akkubuch\app\release\Akkubuch - V.1.3.apk),EarlySyncBuildOutput(type=com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.InternalArtifactType$APK@78c5bc70, apkType=MAIN, filtersData=[], version=0, output=C:\Users\Gereon\AndroidStudioProjects\Akkubuch\app\release\Akkubuch - V.1.4.2.apk),EarlySyncBuildOutput(type=com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.InternalArtifactType$APK@78c5bc70, apkType=MAIN, filtersData=[], version=0, output=C:\Users\Gereon\AndroidStudioProjects\Akkubuch\app\release\Akkubuch - V.1.4.apk),EarlySyncBuildOutput(type=com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.InternalArtifactType$APK@78c5bc70, apkType=MAIN, filtersData=[], version=0, output=C:\Users\Gereon\AndroidStudioProjects\Akkubuch\app\release\Akkubuch - V.1.5.apk),EarlySyncBuildOutput(type=com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.InternalArtifactType$APK@78c5bc70, apkType=MAIN, filtersData=[], version=0, output=C:\Users\Gereon\AndroidStudioProjects\Akkubuch\app\release\Akkubuch - V.1.6.2.apk),EarlySyncBuildOutput(type=com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.InternalArtifactType$APK@78c5bc70, apkType=MAIN, filtersData=[], version=0, output=C:\Users\Gereon\AndroidStudioProjects\Akkubuch\app\release\Akkubuch - V.1.6.apk),EarlySyncBuildOutput(type=com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.InternalArtifactType$APK@78c5bc70, apkType=MAIN, filtersData=[], version=0, output=C:\Users\Gereon\AndroidStudioProjects\Akkubuch\app\release\Akkubuch - V.1.7.2.apk),EarlySyncBuildOutput(type=com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.InternalArtifactType$APK@78c5bc70, apkType=MAIN, filtersData=[], version=0, output=C:\Users\Gereon\AndroidStudioProjects\Akkubuch\app\release\Akkubuch - V.1.7.apk),EarlySyncBuildOutput(type=com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.InternalArtifactType$APK@78c5bc70, apkType=MAIN, filtersData=[], version=0, output=C:\Users\Gereon\AndroidStudioProjects\Akkubuch\app\release\Akkubuch - V.1.8.apk),EarlySyncBuildOutput(type=com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.InternalArtifactType$APK@78c5bc70, apkType=MAIN, filtersData=[], version=0, output=C:\Users\Gereon\AndroidStudioProjects\Akkubuch\app\release\Akkubuch - V.1.9.apk)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.ide.AndroidArtifactImpl.computeBuildOutputs(AndroidArtifactImpl.java:197)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.ide.AndroidArtifactImpl.<init>(AndroidArtifactImpl.java:137)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.ide.ModelBuilder.createAndroidArtifact(ModelBuilder.java:960)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.ide.ModelBuilder.createVariant(ModelBuilder.java:584)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.ide.ModelBuilder.buildAndroidProject(ModelBuilder.java:399)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.ide.ModelBuilder.buildAll(ModelBuilder.java:193)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.AppModelBuilder.buildAll(AppModelBuilder.kt:63)
    at org.gradle.tooling.provider.model.internal.DefaultToolingModelBuilderRegistry$BuildOperationWrappingToolingModelBuilder$1$1.create(DefaultToolingModelBuilderRegistry.java:104)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry.withLenientState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:133)
    at org.gradle.tooling.provider.model.internal.DefaultToolingModelBuilderRegistry$BuildOperationWrappingToolingModelBuilder$1.call(DefaultToolingModelBuilderRegistry.java:100)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
    at org.gradle.tooling.provider.model.internal.DefaultToolingModelBuilderRegistry$BuildOperationWrappingToolingModelBuilder.buildAll(DefaultToolingModelBuilderRegistry.java:97)
    at com.android.tools.lint.gradle.LintGradleExecution.createAndroidProject(LintGradleExecution.java:369)
    at com.android.tools.lint.gradle.LintGradleExecution.analyze(LintGradleExecution.java:88)
    ... 104 more



* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
12 actionable tasks: 5 executed, 7 up-to-date
```

Also 3 other errors plop up:
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid main APK outputs :
Lint infrastructure error
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Comment: please post your gradle file

Comment: which one? the one of the app-module or the project one?

Comment: post your app level build.gradle file here

Comment: it's to long. i posted it here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1HK-om-VvtOEogcZ22GLYlPi5QuFiDvO9. it works btw since i put the lintOptions, but it isn't recommended to put these

Comment: i posted it here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1HK-om-VvtOEogcZ22GLYlPi5QuFiDvO9.

Comment: yea i have seen it.it's fine.nothing problem there.lintOptions false will work definitely.

Comment: thanks. if you say it's fine to use it imma trust you

Comment: I ran into this problem also, pretty annoying since I have no idea what the stack trace is eluding to. The `lintOptions { checkReleaseBuilds false }` did the trick.

Comment: I have same error and the line which caught my attention was this:
`Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid main APK outputs : EarlySyncBuildOutput(type=com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.InternalArtifactType$APK@78c5bc70, apkType=MAIN, filtersData=[], version=0, output=C:\Users\Gereon\AndroidStudioProjects\Akkubuch\app\release\Akkubuch - V.1.1.apk) (...)`
Why does it reference old versions?

Answer (score 27):

OK just had the same issue. Thought I had Lint issues to resolve, but checking App> build > reports > lint-results-release-fatal showed a clean slate.

Tried to clean, but that did not work. So I ended up deleting the 'build' and 'release' folders. Somehow that worked. Don't know what actually caused it.

Comment: Yes, it solved my issue as well. First time it has happened ... maybe thats because I always renamed the apk ... now I dont.

Comment: Perhaps its because of a gradle update or something weird like that? I never rename my apks, and its also the first time it has happened :)

Comment: Also removed `build` and `release` folders. Before I copied, moved files inside `release`. Maybe AS doesn't like these actions.

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me. In my case the package structure of the project changed a lot, that is probably why this manual cleanup was required.

Comment: There was a previously generated AAB file in the app/release folder, which I renamed to something like: appname-1.8.4.aab . The file was causing the problem, after deleting the file everything was back to normal

Answer (score 1):

I removed all content from the destiny folder and then the error disappear.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to find the problems by performing the following actions:
Go to "Analyze" -> Inspect code. After the inspection, the errors should show up.
I've found myself some errors there. Even though it did not work after fixing the errors, I've updated Android studio and it finally solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Doing invalidate cache and restart option as shown below fixed this issue for me[image]